# Possible to allow a uitableview to allow multiple and single selections?

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

Essentially I have a list of items, I want to have some type of checkbox on the end where they can select multiple items.  I also need them to be able to just select one of the rows and have it open up a detail view.  Is this possible?  Or do I need to do something like they do with the messages where you choose the edit button to select them and show an additional button to take action on the selected?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer, there's an option to allow multiple selections on edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

Set your cell's UITableViewAccessoryType property to UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark to make a check mark show up on a certain cell, you'll have to keep track of which cell's are checked on your own though, since this property doesn't track.

So have an array or something that represents which cells ar checked and which aren't, then in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method you can modify the data in the array to reflect the cell's selected state, and call [tableView reloadData] so the checkmark shows up right away.